# Request for Advice c# Webplayer

Tags: c#

I am currently building an asp.net c# Website for a client of mine to promote their band, on there they would like to have a Webplayer which continues to play music as people are browsing the site. The player is located on the Master page so it is included on every site, but it stops playing every time the site does a postback or refreshes in any way.

I think it is possible to achive this using Iframes or Ajax, although i dont have alot of knowledge in either.The site is only about 6 pages with mainly static information on there, so the only postbacks/refreshes will be done by using the navigation menu to load each page.

My question to you is:

how can I achive this?

what would be the easiest method and what are the pros and cons?

are there any other/better ways of achiving this other than using Iframes or Ajax?

I can provide some code if needed.

Thanks,

Seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *easiest* way to achieve this would probably be to have your site put itself into a frame, where another (very small) frame on the page hosts the media player. That way when people switch pages, the frame with the media player is left alone. However, this will probably come out feeling pretty clunky at best.

The *best* way is probably to use AJAX. All of your page navigation would happen as AJAX requests, so the user never technically leaves the original page. An iframe will probably be necessary for tracking history so the user can click "back" and have the browser do what they expect, but you can find libraries that will take care of that aspect for you. The media player should probably use a different subdomain for its source than the rest of the site content, because most browsers max out at two simultaneous connections to the same domain--your site could feel sluggish if one of these two connections is being used for the music stream at all times.